# 3D Transform z-index broken with firefox, preserve-3d not preserved

Tags: html, css, firefox, transform

3D transform in Firefox seems to have issues with z-index. It seems to me that the rendering is "ignoring" the 3D Z position, and simply uses the z-index from DOM. Interesting enough, when the visible portion is made smaller, so that only a part of the wheel is visible, the z-index is suddenly correct, although other artifacts start to appear.

There is this intersection bug demonstration which is bugged since 2011 in Firefox, but my circles are not intersecting - so I hope it is somehow possible.
http://jsfiddle.net/yNfQX/21/

Firefox Bugtracker: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=689498

```css
.perspective {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 3000px;
  display: block;
}
.dcw {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.dc {
  top: calc(50% - 44px);
  left: calc(50% - 44px);
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 88px;
  height: 88px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="perspective">
  <div class="dcw">
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);transform:    rotateZ( 0deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(251,4,4,1);transform:    rotateZ( 10deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(248,7,7,1);transform:    rotateZ( 20deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(244,11,11,1);transform:    rotateZ( 30deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(241,14,14,1);transform:    rotateZ( 40deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(237,18,18,1);transform:    rotateZ( 50deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(234,21,21,1);transform:    rotateZ( 60deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(230,25,25,1);transform:    rotateZ( 70deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(227,28,28,1);transform:    rotateZ( 80deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(223,32,32,1);transform:    rotateZ( 90deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(219,36,36,1);transform:    rotateZ( 100deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(216,39,39,1);transform:    rotateZ( 110deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(212,43,43,1);transform:    rotateZ( 120deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(209,46,46,1);transform:    rotateZ( 130deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(205,50,50,1);transform:    rotateZ( 140deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(202,53,53,1);transform:    rotateZ( 150deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(198,57,57,1);transform:    rotateZ( 160deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(195,60,60,1);transform:    rotateZ( 170deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(191,64,64,1);transform:    rotateZ( 180deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(187,68,68,1);transform:    rotateZ( 190deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(184,71,71,1);transform:    rotateZ( 200deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(180,75,75,1);transform:    rotateZ( 210deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(177,78,78,1);transform:    rotateZ( 220deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(173,82,82,1);transform:    rotateZ( 230deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(170,85,85,1);transform:    rotateZ( 240deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(166,89,89,1);transform:    rotateZ( 250deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(163,92,92,1);transform:    rotateZ( 260deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(159,96,96,1);transform:    rotateZ( 270deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(155,100,100,1);transform:    rotateZ( 280deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(152,103,103,1);transform:    rotateZ( 290deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(148,107,107,1);transform:    rotateZ( 300deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(145,110,110,1);transform:    rotateZ( 310deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(141,114,114,1);transform:    rotateZ( 320deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(138,117,117,1);transform:    rotateZ( 330deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(134,121,121,1);transform:    rotateZ( 340deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
    <div class="dc" style="background-color: rgba(131,124,124,1);transform:    rotateZ( 350deg ) translateX(125px) rotateX( -60deg ); "></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle of it:
https://jsfiddle.net/gvquf0g6/

How it should look like (screenshot from Chrome):
[image: How it should look like (screenshot from Chrome):]

z-index issue (screenshot from Firefox):

[image: z-index issue (screenshot from Firefox)]

Artifact issue, and working z-index with partial visible wheel (screenshot from Firefox):
[image]
[image]

Moving your mouse over the artifacts (missing blocks) fills them in as they should be when first rendered.

Comment: Hm, it seems to only partially work for me in Chrome. macOS 10.12.2, Chrome 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit). [working](https://snag.gy/D8f9K0.jpg) and [not](https://snag.gy/6TdINf.jpg).

Comment: On Firefox 53 it looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EE77F.png), due to [bug 1274673](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1274673)

Comment: @Oriol - I hope that "resolved" flag holds true.  Now how long for 53 since they just recently released [50.1.0](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/50.1.0/releasenotes/) on December 13, 2016 !?

Comment: @KraangPrime See [RapidRelease/Calendar](https://wiki.mozilla.org/RapidRelease/Calendar). Firefox 53 will be released around 2017-04-18.

Comment: Still broken in latest Firefox (54.0.1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, z-ordering is not working fine with cycled layers. It is a known problem that Firefox doesn't handle at all currently. That's an old Firefox bug and you can't fix it until they fix the bug in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime I found a solution, yet its not what I wanted and it ain't perfect either, there appear artifacts and animating it with transition gives many issues. But as a static "image" it seems to work.

Basically the circle is drawn twice, once for the blue half and once for the green half, but just a half of it is visible.

In Chrome its broken, could be solved... but I did care only about firefox.
(And this was really quick and dirty coding, I just looked over it again, and noticed double declared function drawCircle2 ...)
https://jsfiddle.net/7w31uLsL/

```js
$dcw = $(".dcw"); 
var newElement;
var center = 300;
var distance = 200,
  color;
for (var i = 0; i < 360; i = i + 10) {
  color = 20 + Math.round((128 / 360) * i);
  color2 = 220 - Math.round((128 / 360) * i);
  
  $(drawCircle2(color,color2,i,distance)).appendTo($dcw);
}

function drawCircle2(color,color2,rotation,distance) {
 return '<div class="circle" style="transform: translate3d(0,0,0) rotateZ( ' + rotation + 'deg ) translateX('+distance+'px) rotateX(10deg );">' +
  '<div style="background-color: rgba(' + color + ',0,0,1);"></div>' +
  '<div style="background-color: rgba(' + color + ',0,0,1);"></div>' +
 '</div>';
}

function drawCircle2(color,color2,rotation,distance) {
 return '<div class="circle2" style="background-color: rgba(' + color + ',0,0,1);transform: translate3d(0,0,0) rotateZ( ' + rotation + 'deg ) translateX('+distance+'px) rotateX(10deg );">' +
 '</div>';
}
```

```css
.color-wheel {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 3000px;
  display: block;
}

.dcw {
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.dcw:first-child {
  right:50%;
  left:0;
}
.dcw:last-child {  
  right:0;
  left:50%;
}

.dcw:first-child .circle2 {
  left: calc(100% - 94px);
}
.dcw:last-child .circle2 {
  left: calc(0% - 94px);
}

.circle2 {
  top: calc(50% - 94px);
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 188px;
  height: 188px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.circle {
  top: calc(50% - 94px);
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 188px;
  height: 188px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.circle div {
  left:0;
  right:0;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
.circle div:first-child {
  
  border-top-left-radius:1000px;
  border-top-right-radius:1000px;
  top: 0;
  bottom:50%
}
.circle div:last-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius:1000px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:1000px;
  bottom: 0;
  top:50%;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
<div class="color-wheel">
  <div class="dcw" style="background-color:blue;">

  </div>
  <div class="dcw" style="background-color:green;">

  </div>
</div>
```